# Dynamically change background of body in html

Tags: html, css, jsp

In our application, I've to write JSP which I upload to an application and as per JSP UI is reflected.

In this I make API call and get value of `Rating` which is A, B, C, D or E. I've some code to achieve that and store in variable -

```
String reliabilityRating = getRating();
```

Based on rating, I want to change background of the page. CSS are like follows -

```
.rating-A {
    line-height: 23px;
    background-color: #00aa00;
}
.rating-B {
    background-color: #b0d513;
}

.rating-C {
    background-color: #eabe06;
}
```

To change background based on rating, I can have html like -

```
<body class="rating-A">
```

But this is fixed. I want to make it dynamic like `rating-X` where X can be A, B, C, D or E. Hence I tried calling method which returns rating like

```
<body class="rating-" + getRating()>
```

But this is not helping to achieve what I want. Could you please suggest how I can change background of page based on value of specific variable?

Comment: Post full JSP code please

Comment: something might be preventing these classes from applying bg colors, try more specific css like body.rating-A, body.rating-B, body.rating-C etc. Also its worth mentioning that in some cases class names are case sensitive and thus be consistent in all areas. Without more information on how jsp is printing class names, no  further suggestion can be made. Also you can apply !important to forcefully ignore other rules like : background-color: #eabe06 !important

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this tutorial](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3336161/what-is-jsp-introduction-to-javaserver-pages.html), if you want to output the content of a Java expression you need to wrap it in `${` and `}`.

Therefore:

```
<body class="rating-${getRating()}">
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best approach you can use in this scenario is using a custom data attribute in the body tag that works as metadata and change it from the js file.

Here is a demo:

```js
const body = document.body;

const changeRating = rating => body.setAttribute('data-rating', rating);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
[data-rating="A"] {
    line-height: 23px;
    background-color: #00aa00;
}
[data-rating="B"] {
    background-color: #b0d513;
}

[data-rating="C"] {
    background-color: #eabe06;
}
```

```html
<body data-rating="A">
</body>

<button onclick="changeRating('A')">Rating A</button>
<button onclick="changeRating('B')">Rating B</button>
<button onclick="changeRating('C')">Rating C</button>
```

Comment: This is JavaScript. The question is tagged [tag:jsp]. The JavaScript has no way to run the `getRating` function.